# Replicating regex expression using Rebus package in R

Tags: r, regex

I would like to create a pattern for the following text string using the `rebus` package in R.

My attempts are below, but I am not able to remove the square brackets and return the same pattern using `str_view()`. Is there perhaps a tool / function that can replicate regex expressions using the rebus package? Rebus is a lot easier to read and makes sense when sharing code with someone that might not be familiar with regex.

Pattern with regex:

```
pattern = "http.*for-sale.*5857"
```

I am trying to replicate this with the rebus package:

```
pattern_rebus = "http" %R% zero_or_more(ANY_CHAR) %R% "for-sale" %R% zero_or_more(ANY_CHAR) %R% "5857"

as.regex(pattern_rebus)
<regex> http[.]*for-sale[.]*5857
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in `rebus`, it wraps all the repeated (`one_or_more` or `zero_or_more`) chars with `[` and `]`, a character class. That is why `.*` should be added manually.

```r
pattern_rebus = "http" %R% ".*" %R% "for-sale" %R% ".*5857"
as.regex(pattern_rebus)
## => <regex> http.*for-sale.*5857
```

However, you may use a workaround, `[\s\S]` instead of a `.` will match any chars if you use a PCRE regex (with base R regex functions) or ICU regex (with *stringr* regex functions):

```r
pattern_rebus = "http" %R% zero_or_more(char_class(WRD, NOT_WRD)) %R% "for-sale" %R% zero_or_more(char_class(WRD, NOT_WRD)) %R% "5857"
as.regex(pattern_rebus)
## => <regex> http[\w\W]*for-sale[\w\W]*5857
```

Or, if you want to match any char but CR and LF:

```r
pattern_rebus = "http" %R% zero_or_more(negated_char_class("\\r\\n")) %R% "for-sale" %R% zero_or_more(negated_char_class("\\r\\n")) %R% "5857"
as.regex(pattern_rebus)
## => <regex> http[^\r\n]*for-sale[^\r\n]*5857
```